# PHP is_writable error returns not writable

Tags: php, permissions, directory

I have this code

```
if(is_writable($destination)){ 
  print "destination is writable"; 
}
else { 
 print "destination is not writable"; 
}
```

`$destination` is a relative path like `../subdir/dir/currectDir/` and I have checked and the permission is 777 but this code above returns "destination is not writable" and I don't understand why. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Problem solved, I had to change the permissions via my ISP and not via FTP...

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons why a directory may not be writable, aside from permissions. Some of them are:

- The directory is outside of the paths which PHP is able to write to because of open_basedir restrictions
- The directory is on a drive which is mounted as read-only
- The directory has immutable or appendonly attributes set
- The filesystem is corrupt

However, my guess in this case would be that the path you are using is not correct. Try running

```
echo getcwd();
```

Just before your is_writable() call.

It will tell you the current directory the PHP script is running in, and from there you should be able to work out the correct relative path. Not that if running a PHP script from the command line its path will be that of the current directory, whereas running via a web server such as Apache it will usually be the public_html or httpdocs directory. It may have also been changed earlier on in the script execution.

You can also specify an absolute path (e.g. /home/youruser/public_html/subdir/dir/currectDir)

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer, now I have another problem, I must do this: "if(@move_uploaded_file($tempNameFile, $destination.$FileName)) { ... }else{ print "UPLOADING ERROR"; }" and despite $destination is a writable directory, it returns "UPLOADING ERROR".

Comment: `echo $tempNameFile` and `echo $destination.$FileName` to make sure they are correct. Also check the PHP error_log file to see if there are any more specific errors or warnings. There are also plenty of examples online or processing a file upload in PHP.

Comment: "$tempNameFile" and "$destination.$FileName" are correct. 
Excuse me for my inexperience but I can't find the "PHP error log"

Comment: Make an empty php script called phpinfo.php and put in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then view it in a browser, search it for 'error_log' and that will tell you where the log is. Make sure you delete the phpinfo.php file before your code goes live!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I have to respond here but it looks as though the path (you posted a relative path, not an absolute path by the way) is incorrect - have you tried

```
var_dump(file_exists($destination));
```

first, to determine if you are looking in the right place for your directory?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my error.
The path is correct and I must do this:
"if(@move_uploaded_file($tempNameFile, $destination.$FileName))
{
...
}else{
print "UPLOADING ERROR";
}  
" and also if I use a writable directory, it returns "UPLOADING ERROR".
Sorry if I have made some errors also here.

Comment: This is really a comment to go in the comments of the answer above.. but again I can't add comments so I have to do it here! Just following on from Chris Wheeler's advice to check the PHP error_log, before you do that. remove the @ symbol from your function call, as this is an error suppressor, which means no errors will be generated even from the failed call.

Comment: If you do not have an error log on the server, try adding the following code your .htaccess file in the root of your project to output errors to the browser: `php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on`

Comment: excuse me, but I don't have understood what I must do :(

Comment: in your project root, if you have a file called .htaccess, add the following lines to it `php_flag display_startup_errors on php_flag display_errors on php_flag html_errors on php_flag log_errors on` (each line ending in 'on' should be on a new line, this will set the php configuration for your project to display errors in the browser), then remove the @ symbol from your move_uploaded_file function call, then try running your script again - whatever error you are receiving when you try to move the uploaded file should be displayed in your browser

Comment: I don't have the ".htaccess" file but I see this :
"Warning: move_uploaded_file('relative path whit file name') [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in 'page path' on line 56

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\PHP\upload\php3266.tmp' to 'relative path and file name' in 'page path' on line 56"